# Windows server 2008 R2 Active Directory can not enable LDAPS

Tags: active-directory

I'm setup a new Active Directory on my Windows server (Windows server 2008 R2).

And it is working fine for port 389. I need use LDAPS protocol to modify password from other system.

According to this post https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/321051/how-to-enable-ldap-over-ssl-with-a-third-party-certification-authority, the only thing is import a certificate for enable LDAPS.

But when I imported the SSL certificate and restart the domain controller, I cannot see port 636 is opening.

My SSL certificate is issued by GeoTrust, and using for website. The website domain same with AD DS FQDN. I'm not sure is it OK.

How can I check what's the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

1. I would start by check the certificate enhanced key usage, make sure the Server Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1) are in the enhanced key usage. This can be done by open the certificate and click on "details" tab and scroll to "Enhanced Key Usage"
2. On the domain controller open an MMC and add certificate snap-in with local computer and verify if the certificate is in the personal certificates. If the certificate is there you can double-click on the certificate under General tab did you see a line at the bottom stating "You have a private key that corresponds to this certificate."?

When you say "I cannon see port 636 is opening" how are you doing about doing that? Did you run netstat on the domain controller to see if the server is listing?
syntax: netstat -an | find "636" 
-a display connection and listening ports
-n display ip

find "636" is to filter for port 636. Because this is a domain controller you will have a lot of connections.

Also, if you have access to openssl you can try the following

syntax: openssl s_client -connect domain_controller_ip:636

if the certificate configure properly and the domain is listening to port 636/tcp. you will get the certificate information return.

Comment: Yes, I did use `netstat` for check listening ports. And I am sure the certificate include `Server Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1)` in the Enhanced Key Usage.

Another warning information is: 
*
LDAP over Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) will be unavailable at this time because the server was unable to obtain a certificate. 
 
Additional Data 
Error value:
8009030e No credentials are available in the security package
*

Comment: have you try telenet to the domain controller on port 636? The error 800903e, look like the front end web server need a ssl certificate.

Comment: Yes, the problem is my ssl certificate has problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is certificate not match.

My AD domain is xyz.com, I thought my certificate `Common Name` should be xyz.com, it's wrong.

The right `Common Name` of the certificate should be `Full computer name` or `Computer name`+`Domain`. My computer name is `ad`, then I need the `Common Name` is `ad.xyz.com` of the certificate.